# Unnamed namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, g++

There is following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace
{
    int funkcja()
    {
        cout << "unnamed" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}

int funkcja()
{
    cout << "global" << endl;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    ::funkcja(); //this works, it will call funkcja() from global scope
    funkcja(); //this generates an error 
    return 0;    
}
```

I use g++. Is there some way to call function from unnamed namespace in such situation? It is possible to call function from global scope using ::function, but how to call function from unnamed namespace? Compiler generates an error:

```
prog3.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog3.cpp:43:17: error: call of overloaded ‘funkcja()’ is ambiguous
prog3.cpp:32:5: note: candidates are: int funkcja()
prog3.cpp:25:6: note:                 int<unnamed>::funkcja()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Is there some way to call function from unnamed namespace in such situation?***
No, Not in your case.

***Anonymous/UnNamed namespaces**  allow variables and functions to be visible within an entire translation unit*, yet not visible externally. Although entities in an unnamed namespace might have external linkage, they are effectively qualified by a name unique to their translation unit and therefore can never be seen from any other translation unit.

This means your function `funkcja` inside the Unnamed Namespace is visible in the translation unit which defines a global function `funkcja`. This causes two same named functions defined in the global scope and thus causing the redefinition error.

If `funkcja` was only present in your UnNamed Namespace then You would have been able to call it by `::funkcja` as it would be in your global scope. To conclude, you can call functions in UnNamed Namespace depending on the scope in which the UnNamed Namespace is present.

Answer (score 5):

The way that anonymous namespaces work is that the names declared inside them are automatically visible in the enclosing scope as if a `using namespace name_of_anonymous_namespace;` had been issued.

Because of this, in your example the name `funkcja` is ambiguous and un-disambiguatable [new word!]. It looks like you don't really want an anonymous namespace, you really need a properly named namespace.